# In two-way between-groups ANOVA, is there a way to work out $SS_{A×B}$ aside from $SS_{\rm BETWEEN} - SS_A - SS_B$?

Tags: anova, interaction

A textbook I am using (Field's "Discovering Statistics Using SPSS") declares that "the simplest way" to work things out is to calculate SS<sub>A×B</sub> as SS<sub>BETWEEN</sub> - SS<sub>A</sub> - SS<sub>B</sub>.

This left me wondering if there might be some other way to calculate SS<sub>A×B</sub>. I'm especially, though not exclusively, keen to know if there's a way of calculating it that would be more intuitive.

Comment: You can perform ANOVA directly as linear regression with contrast variables (such as dummies) obtained out of the two factors. Then "AB" will be a separate predictor(s) and you get their SS directly.